# Facing NPE when upgrading scala from 2.11 to 2.12 in flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, rocksdb

Upgrading to flink 1.13.5_2.12 from 1.13.5_2.11 and skipped state but facing NPE when RocksDb state is updating.
Have a PriorityQueue which is ordered by Long, and when its updating  state, an error is thrown
Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkRuntimeException: Error while adding data to RocksDB
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBValueState.update(RocksDBValueState.java:109)
    at myClass.saveAdEventQueue(myClass.scala:251)
    at myClass.processElement1(myClass.scala:114)
    at myClass.processElement1(myClass.scala:30)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.KeyedCoProcessOperator.processElement1(KeyedCoProcessOperator.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.processRecord1(StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.java:213)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.lambda$create$0(StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.java:178)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(StreamTwoInputProcessorFactory.java:291)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:134)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:96)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:423)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:204)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:684)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.executeInvoke(StreamTask.java:639)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runWithCleanUpOnFail(StreamTask.java:650)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:623)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:779)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

```
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Serialization trace:
f$2 (scala.math.Ordering$$anon$10)
$outer (scala.math.Ordering$$anon$4)
ord (scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:82)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:495)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:523)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:61)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:495)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:523)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:61)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:495)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:599)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.serialize(KryoSerializer.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.serializeValueInternal(AbstractRocksDBState.java:158)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.serializeValue(AbstractRocksDBState.java:180)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.serializeValue(AbstractRocksDBState.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBValueState.update(RocksDBValueState.java:107)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Have you updated your whole project to 2.12 as well?

Comment: Yes, all libraries are of 2.12